# How to Encode Authorization:Bearer

Tags: json, token, encode, postman, bearer-token

How to Encode `Authorization:Bearer` parameter value in PostMan. It is passed in Header as a JSON request.

```
http://localhost:52586/api/Location1/6

Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer {{Location1AdminToken}}
```

[image: Postman Preview]

Comment: Try `base64` as a common encoding. Note there are variations such as https://jwt.io/#debugger-io which can make it a bit more tricky.